# Why does my Python binary search algorithm not work for certain items?

Tags: python, computer-science, binary-search

My binary search algorithm manages to find some items but does not find others:

```py
myList = [1,3,4,7,12,13,14,16,19,20,28,29,40,45,48,50,67,89,91,94]

item = 67
found = False
lowerBound = 0
upperBound = len(myList) - 1
index = 0

while not found and lowerBound != upperBound:
    index = (upperBound+lowerBound) // 2
    if item == myList[index]:
        found=True
    if item > myList[index]:
        lowerBound = index+1
    if item < myList[index]:
        upperBound = index-1


if found:
    print('Item found')
else:
    print('Item not found')
```

For example, it manages to find 91, 89, 50, 48, 40, 29, etc., but doesn't find 94, 67, 45, or 28.

There seems to be a pattern in the numbers it finds and those it doesn't. Did I make a mistake somewhere in the code?

Comment: If `lowerBound` and `upperBound` ever become equal (in other words, there's only one possible index that could contain the value), you exit the loop before checking if that index contains the value.

Comment: `lowerBound <= upperBound` not `lowerBound != upperBound`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the statement in the while loop. You wrote while lowerBound != upperBound, but that is wrong because if the value at that index is the right value, then you just exit the loop without checking. That can be fixed by using a different condition which is lowerBound <= upperBound. That is a safer and more correct condition to use in this case. The code with the correction made is bellow:

```
myList = [1,3,4,7,12,13,14,16,19,20,28,29,40,45,48,50,67,89,91,94]

item = 94
found = False
lowerBound = 0
upperBound = len(myList) - 1
index = 0

while not found and lowerBound <= upperBound:
    index = (upperBound+lowerBound) // 2
    if item == myList[index]:
        found=True
    if item > myList[index]:
        lowerBound = index+1
    if item < myList[index]:
        upperBound = index-1


if found:
    print('Item found')
else:
    print('Item not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use while not found and lowerBound <= upperBound
Listing iteration of 67
(lowerBound,upperBound)
(0,19)
(10,19)
(15,19)
(15,16)
(16,16)
While you algorithm make exit at same lowerBound and upperBound